# How to calculate the combined standard error of two models?

Tags: regression, standard-error

Let's say you have a model that predicts annual GDP growth.  It has a standard error of 2%. 
You have a second model that predicts annual stock returns.  It has a standard error of 6%. 
What is the standard error when you estimate stock returns based on estimates of GDP growth?

Comment: It is impossible to tell with the information given. Are other variables involved in the stock return model besides GDP growth? What are the range and distribution of GDP growth values? Does the stock return model accommodate a random component in its explanatory variable(s) or not?  What are the estimated coefficients in the stock return model?

Comment: This is a simple example to capture the relevant calculation.  So, the stock market return model is based solely on GDP growth.  The second and third questions are not directly relevant.  This is a made up example to ask the question.  See my answer below.  Do you think it is right?

Comment: As I interpret the question, I do not think your answer is correct. Suppose, say, the stock return regression estimates that the returns equal $-15 + 10\text{[GDP Growth]}$ (in %). Then a $\pm 2$% variation in GDP growth gets amplified to a $\pm 20$% variation in stock returns *plus* more uncertainty due to the standard error in the stock return regression. I hope this indicates why the questions I asked are not merely theoretical or nit-picking: they are crucial.

Comment: whuber, see my edited answer I think it is getting closer if not downright correct.  What do you think?

Comment: Gaetan, are you talking about the standard errors (the square root of the estimated variance of a regression coefficient) or the RMSE (the square root of the estimated residual variance)?

Comment: The latter, the RMSE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is still hard to gauge what exactly you are trying to achieve, but I think you would need to use [Murphy-Topel standard errors](http://www.citeulike.org/user/ctacmo/article/816962) to get it right. Their calculation involves getting the scores from the first equation and plugging them into the second equation, so that the sampling error in the predictor is propagated properly into two stages. Thus, they are adding the contribution of the sampling variability from the first stage (GDP prediction) to the second stage (stock market), and have the result as the sum of two matrices. [Hardin (2002)](http://www.citeulike.org/user/ctacmo/article/4735885) utilized the same idea and arrived at a different, single-stage estimator that wraps together the scores from both equations.

Answer (score -1):

I gave it some thought and I think you could use the group standard error formula from the unpaired t test and factor within it the coefficient of GDP (let's call it A) to estimate stock return:

group standard error = SQRT(A^2*2%^2 + 5%^2).
Here A is the coefficient of GDP to estimate stock return.

Comment: This assumes independence..